# OpenIdConnect with .NET Core 2.2 MVC towards IdentityServer3 using ScopePolicy. How do you get scopes into user principal?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver3

It seems to set up OpenIdConnect authentication from .NET Core 2.2 to IdentityServer3 I have to setup through generic AddOpenIdConnect() call, and in order for scope policy to work, I have overridden `OnTokenValidated`, where I parse the access token received, and add the scopes in it to the `ClaimsPrincipal` object.

I have found no other way of getting scope policy to work. This seems a bit hackish though. Is there a better or simpler way, so I don't need to override events, or at least not parse the access token? It is parsed in the framework anyhow, so I would suspect there were other functionality available to get scopes into the claims principal.

Moving our code from .NET 4.5.2 to .NET Core 2.2, I need to set up authentication towards our `IdentityServer3` server in a very different way.

I was hoping new functionality in later framework allowed for simple setup of authentication towards `IdentityServer3`, but I've found no fitting example.

I saw someone saying that `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation` NuGet package could work towards `IdentityServer3`, but only example I've found has been with simple JWT authentication not allowing implicit user login flow.

Consequently, I've ended up using standard ASP.NET Core libraries to set up openidconnect, and then I need to tweak the code to make it work.

Not sure if the code below handles all it needs to, but at least I've gotten where I can log in and use the new web site, and write cypress tests. Any suggestions on how to do this better or simpler would be appreciated.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Without this, I get "Correlation failed." error from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddAuthentication(o => {
        o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        o.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddCookie().AddOpenIdConnect(o =>
    {
        o.Authority = "https://myidentityserver3.myfirm.com";
        o.ClientId = "myidentityserver3clientname";
        o.SignedOutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:50011/signout";

        o.ResponseType = "id_token token";
        o.SaveTokens = true;
        o.Scope.Add("openid");
        o.Scope.Add("roles");
        o.Scope.Add("profile");
        o.Scope.Add("customrequiredscopeforapi");
        o.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = false;

        {
            var old = o.Events.OnTokenValidated;
            o.Events.OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
            {
                if (old != null) await old(ctx);
                var token = MyCustomAuthUtils.ParseBearerToken(ctx.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);
                foreach (var scope in token.Scopes)
                {
                    ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim("Scope", scope) }));
                }
                // Our controllers need access token to call other web api's, so putting it here.
                // Not sure if that is a good way to do it.
                ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim("access_token", ctx.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken) }));
            };
        }
    });

    var mvcBuilder = services.AddMvc(o =>
    {
        o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(ScopePolicy.Create("customrequiredscopeforapi")));
    });
    services.AddAuthorization();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is you don't need to manally decode the access token , just use `ctx.SecurityToken.Claims` in `OnTokenValidated` event to get all claims included in the token .

I'm not sure why you need to use `scope` to identify the permission . The scope parameter in the OIDC-conformant pipeline determines:

- The permissions that an authorized application should have for a given resource server
- Which standard profile claims should be included in the ID Token (if the user consents to provide this information to the application)

You can use `role` to identify whether current login user could access the protected resource . And the OpenID Connect middleware will help mapping the `role` claim to claim principle .

Comment: I was expecting to find scopes as claims too, but they're not there, and not in ctx.SecurityToken, so to get Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.ScopePolicy to work, I've found no other way than to manually add them. Maybe there's some setting I'm missing to have them included as claims by default.

Exactly why people here have chosen to use scopes to limit access is a bit uncertain, and they are no longer present. Maybe we can get away with roles only, but I don't want to change that in order to move code to .NET Core, if workaround above is sufficient.